# Convert Blocking python function to async function

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, fastapi

So currently I have 4 api requests which are called in synchronous method using a third_party lib which is synchronous. What i want is to run them in parallel. So that my total time to call all 4 apis is reduced.

I am using fastapi as micro framework.

utilities.py

```
async def get_api_1_data():
    data = some_third_party_lib()
    return data

async def get_api_2_data():
    data = some_third_party_lib()
    return data

async def get_api_3_data():
    data = some_third_party_lib()
    return data

async def get_api_4_data():
    data = some_third_party_lib()
    return data
```

my main.py looks something like this

```
import asyncio
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def fetch_new_exposure_api_data(node: str):
   functions_to_run = [get_api_1_data(), get_api_2_data(), get_api_3_data(), get_api_4_data()]
   r1, r2, r3, r4 = await asyncio.gather(*functions_to_run)
   return [r1, r2, r3, r4]
```

So the issue is i can not put await in front of `some_third_party_lib()` as it's not a async lib it's a sync lib.
So is there any way i can convert them to async functionality to run them in parallel.

Comment: You might have more luck with `multiprocessing` if you can't do anything about the underlying library - they'll never give up any resources to the asyncio loop if they're not async compatible - async does not make thing run in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you *cannot* make a synchronous function asynchronous without changing its implementation. If `some_third_party_lib()` is a synchronous function, you cannot make it run in parallel using the `asyncio` library.

One workaround is to run each of the calls to `some_third_party_lib()` in a separate *thread*. You can use the `concurrent.futures` library in *Python* to create and manage *a pool of worker threads*. Here's an example setup that I came up with:

```
import concurrent.futures

def get_api_1_data():
    return some_third_party_lib()

def get_api_2_data():
    return some_third_party_lib()

def get_api_3_data():
    return some_third_party_lib()

def get_api_4_data():
    return some_third_party_lib()

@app.get("/")
async def fetch_new_exposure_api_data(node: str):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = [executor.submit(fn) for fn in [get_api_1_data, get_api_2_data, get_api_3_data, get_api_4_data]]

    return [result.result() for result in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results)]
```

This way, each call to `some_third_party_lib()` will run in a separate thread and they will run in parallel. Note that the order of the results in the returned list may not match the order of the functions in the `functions_to_run` list.